# How to drag and drop items between 2 columns with "Konva.JS"?

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I'm looking for a way to drag and drop items between 2 columns with Konva.JS. 
Since I found [a sample code using Sortable.JS](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists), I ported it and wrote the following code. With this code, I expected there were two vertical independent scroll bars, such as in this example image:

[image: one scrollbar for each column]

However, there aren't, as shown in this image from running my code:

[image: no scrollbars].

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@5.0.2/konva.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                background-color: #f0f0f0;
                height:100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #Leftcontainer {
                overflow: auto;
            }
            #Rightcontainer {
                overflow: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="Leftcontainer"></div> <!-- Left Column -->
            <div id="Rightcontainer"></div> <!-- Right Column -->
        </div>
        <script>
            var width = window.innerWidth;
            var height = window.innerHeight;
            var stage = new Konva.Stage({
                container: 'container',
                width: width,
                height: 60*1090,
            });
            //Layer 1
            var layer = new Konva.Layer();
            stage.add(layer);

            //Layer 2
            var tempLayer = new Konva.Layer();
            stage.add(tempLayer);

            //Load Image (Group of Left Column)
            var leftGroup = new Konva.Group({
                id: 'Leftcontainer',
            });
            layer.add(leftGroup);
            for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                var imageObj = new Image();
                imageObj.src = './assets/apple.jpg';
                imageObj.addEventListener('load', function() {
                    var dragImage = new Konva.Image({
                        x: 5,
                        y: 20+(5+100)*i,
                        image: imageObj,
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        draggable: false,
                    });
                    leftGroup.add(dragImage);
                    layer.draw();
                });
            };

            //Load Text (Group of Right Column)
            var rightGroup = new Konva.Group({
                id: 'Rightcontainer',
            });
            layer.add(rightGroup);
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                var WordLabel = new Konva.Label({
                    x: 300,
                    y: 18+60*i,
                    opacity: 0.75,
                    draggable: true,
                    fill: 'green',
                });
                WordLabel.add(
                    new Konva.Tag({
                        fill: 'green',
                        lineJoin: 'round'
                    })
                );
                WordLabel.add(
                    new Konva.Text({
                        text: "Apple",
                        fontFamily: 'Calibri',
                        fontSize: 18,
                        padding: 5,
                        fill: 'white',
                    })
                );
                rightGroup.add(WordLabel);
            };
            layer.draw();

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please remember that this is not a general help forum, and has [specific things you can and cannot ask here](/help/on-topic). This is one of those "that's not what this site is for" questions. As much as they ask you to post to SO, this is one of those "if you didn't find that on their own site, it's time to file an issue requesting they add it".

Comment: Hi, Mike. Thanks for your comment. Do yo think that looking for how to drag and drop using Konva.JS is also one of those "that's not what this site is for" questions? Pictorial dictionary is a background thing to help people to understand my question. So, I rewrote the sentence of my question to emphasize technical perfume somehow. Would it be safe that I can be here? (BTW, you make interesting website about Japanese! I'm a Japanese!!)

Comment: The request for people ot provide you with example code is definitely off topic. It's one of the preset reasons to close a question. if you haven't written code yet, start there: you have code that works with sortable.js, so learn how that works, learn how konva works, and start trying to port the code from one to the other. And if you get stuck, with actual code that you can reduce to concrete porting problems, and after having done your own searching and researching for what might be wrong or why it doesn't work, _that's_ when Stackoverflow is absolutely (one of) the right place(s) to ask.

Comment: Hi, Mike. Thanks for your comment. Based on your comment. I re-re-wrote my question. Let me know if it isn't adequate. Thanks!

Comment: That's much better, thank you. I've updated the syntax so that the images show _as images_ (remember to put the `!` in front of the markdown), but can you still crop those images to only show what's necessary? Showing 6.5 apples doesn't show people anything 1.5 apples won't already show off, and you can crop the dual scrollbar image to just show the area that _has_ those scrollbars with a tiny bit of image above and below it.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thank you so much for your updating (correcting) the syntax. I will follow your advice and the format from now. I'm educated! I cropped the images to avoid redundancy based on your advice. Please let me know if you notice further improvements toward the ideal state. Thanks again for your comments and great patience!!

Comment: Only that it looks like there is very little reason to use Konva here: you're drawing images on a canvas, but it makes far more sense to just do this in plain HTML and plain JS: a column is trivially effected by making your left and right containers use `display: flex` with an explicit height, and `flex-direction: column`. Then you can just build pairs of `<img>` and `<p`> elements (in JS) such that they know each other, add them to the left and right container (basically same as you do now) and use normal JS drag-and-drop event handling to see whether drags are for matching elements.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for your comment which helped me to understand where I am now. I have a blind spot for that kind of thing. When I search what I need, I've always done that based on concrete examples, and/but examples of to explain how to use a WRAPPER of something "X" (HTML5 canvas in this case) look more realistic than Examples to explain "X" itselt, in my case. So, I used Konva.JS without knowing HTML5 canvas. This is my chronic illness. So doctors like you to point out my condition is appreciated. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that you are intending there to be two columns on your page since you have the HTML for the container, Leftcontainer and Rightcontainer. You then appear to be setting a Konva stage in the 'container' div but later creating Konva groups to co-relate to left + right containers.  You then make these groups long and expect there to be vertical scrollbars.

You are making a false assumption regarding the relationship between the HTML5 canvas (for  which Konva is a wrapper) and its interaction with HTML elements. The basic principle is that an HTML5 canvas 'lives' inside a single HTML element. You cannot 'share' bits of it between HTML elements in the way that you are attempting.

[Aside: Under the covers, Konva DOES create a stage per layer, but that still does not allow placing those layers into other host containers than the main stage.]

Options:

1 - you do not specifically require a canvas-based solution to provide an image-based drag & drop. You would already have found this with sortable.js. But if you are simply using this as a learning activity to understand the canvas then well done you!

2 - continuing this the canvas approach, your basic architecture of a stage and a group per column is reasonable. But you have to take care of producing the scroll bars since in the world of canvas there are no such handy UI shortcuts.

3 - again following a canvas solution, ignore the main 'container' element, and  create a stage in EACH of the left and right container elements to represent your left and right columns. Draw the content, then approach the problem as one of dragging an element from one canvas to another.

Comment: Hi Mr./Ms. Vanquished Wombat,

Thank you very much for your great advice, which helped me not to come grips with Option #3. That's impossible for me who just started to lerarn JavaScript three weeks ago. I will go opposit, that is, port a sample code of collision detection (between a mouse pointer and an image) using Konva.JS (https://konvajs.org/docs/drag_and_drop/Drop_Events.html) into the sample code using sortable.js which has two separete scroll bars. You are my GOD. Thank you so much for your being here. Best Regards!

Comment: @Rio - if my answer helped then please mark it as correct. This helps future readers 
 judge the quality & accuracy of an answer. Also an answered question gives a future reader a better opportunity than one that is left incomplete. Also, well done for diving into JS and congratulations you have come a long way in 3 weeks!  In SO it is advised to keep questions as specific as possible, so if/when you have further issues then please create a new question for each one.

Comment: Hi Mr./Ms. Vanquished Wombat, I've checked V-mark at the left side of your comment. Would it be correct that "mark it as correct" is to check the V-mark? Your answer is much more than "correctness". I was so lucky to read it. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Thanks. Also, things tend to be informal here so you can just refer to a user by their screen name, so I would be @VanquishedWombat. You marked my question complete with the tick. The up-vote arrow adds a further usefulness indicator for the answer - you can use it on comments too, and the down-vote. The original poster (the OP, = you) gets notified of all comments.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sorry, how can I find your screen name is @VanquishedWombat? A part of the URL of your profile page is "vanquished-wombat", and your profile page is "Vanquished Wombat"(whch has a space in the middle). Yes, I marked the tick mark, pressed the up-arrow beside your answer several times and appreciated your comments in my mind many times. Thanks so much!!  By the way, I cannot find such a tick mark and up- and down- arrows beside comments. Would you advice? I just see a flag-icon. Since someone (named Mike) helped me a lot, I would like to press them.

Comment: Ah -re buttons, some of the buttons only become accessible when you get more reputation points. Re screen name - sorry typo on my side, but just start typing @ and the UI will offer any matching screen names associated with the thread.

Comment: I just got UP-arrow showing right above FLAG-icon! My reputation might reach a certain level. So I clicked it. As for screen name, any candidates didn't show up although I typed "@" here. My reputation might not still enough. Also I haven't gotten re-button. Thank you for your comments. Owing to you, I could go to the next step.